# Caching OpenID Connect metadata (.well-known/openid-configuration)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

In the OIDC Authentication process, our Identity Application gets highest traffic from clients for the route "/well-known/openid-configuration" what's the best practice to cache this and respond to clients as getting meta data involves http calls internally. Please do share best practices in rendering wellknown information.

Comment: What OIDC provider you use?

Comment: Multiple Providers involved, this API that provides well-known meta information is a gateway that routes calls to dedicated Identity Provides based on the incoming call request information

Comment: This is entirely up to you. If calls to your own endpoint fan out to downstream OPs, I would recommend looking at at the caching headers of the OPs' endpoints, and picking the shortest expiration time as a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Cache-Control` headers in the response - just like any other HTTP response, `max-age` will tell you how long you can reasonably cache the response.